# Is there the generic properites

Tags: java

Is there a generic properties in Java?

Properties taks generic Hashmap inside, but itself seems is nongenric, is there generic properties?

Comment: In what circumstances would you need a generic Properties class?

Comment: What would that do? Properties is a Map<String, String>, what would you want to parameterise?

Comment: would that container be homogeneous ?

Comment: its EntrySet method is coming from HashMap which returns Map<Object, Object>, I want something returned to be Map<String,String>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the standard API. You would have to roll your own (which by the way is quite easy).

Still though, I'm not sure I see any use of it. If the class itself should be non-generic, i.e. have a non-generic interface, what does it matter if it's internal structure is generic or not?

Answer (score 0):

> its EntrySet method is coming from HashMap which returns Map, I want something returned to be Map

Yes, that is unwieldy. Since JDK1.6 there is at least a `getStringPropertyNames`, which returns a `Set<String>` (as opposed to the old `Enumeration<?>`).